# cannot insert data in table manually through server explorer in visual studio when code first migration is used

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework-migrations

I wanted to insert data manually in table.
when i do so, i get this error [see image below]
how to fix this issue
please help
[error Image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6kV4.png)

Comment: The error spells it out: You have a non-nullable foreign key MembershipTypeId which must be filled in with an existing value from that table. Nothing to do with migrations. Did you want that to be nullable?

Comment: I don't want it to be nullable. Please advice me on what should I do to insert data in table @SteveGreene

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this migrations, and it appears you are trying to get data into your tables that mechanism is called [Seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3). You can override the Seed() method like this:

```
protected override void Seed(MyDbContext context)
{
    context.Customers.AddOrUpdate(
        c => c.Name,   // Use Name (or some other unique field) instead of Id
        new Customer
        {
            Name = "Customer 1",
            IsSubscribed = false,
            MembershipTypeId = 1 // A value from MembershipType table
        },
        new Customer
        {
            Name = "Customer 2",
            IsSubscribed = true,
            MembershipTypeId = 2 // A value from MembershipType table
        });

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now, when you run `update-database` this code will run and if the customers are not in the database, they will be added. If you delete the database they will be added next time you run migrations.

If you just want to manually insert, then you will need to provide a valid MembershipTypeId in that column (search you MembershipType table for valid values).